# Как сделать запрос к chrome.storage не асинхронно?

Tags: javascript, ajax, chrome-extension, синхронизация

Пишу расширение для Хрома.
На странице `Options` сохраняю некоторые параметры с помощью `chrome.storage.sync.set`:

```
chrome.storage.sync.set({
  x: document.getElementById('a').value,
  y: document.getElementById('b').value,
  z: document.getElementById('c').value
}, function() {...});
```

Дальше в `Content script'е` хочу выполнить нужное мне в зависимости от значения этих параметров.
Сперва при загрузке нужной страницы достаю эти данные и присваиваю их значения некоторым переменным:

```
var baseA = "";
var baseB = "";
var baseC = "";

chrome.storage.sync.get({
    x: "",
    y: "",
    z: ""
}, function(items) {
    setValues(items.x, items.y, items.z);
});

function setValues(v1,v2,v3) {
    baseA = v1;
    baseB = v2;
    baseC = v3;
    console.log('baseA | ' + baseA);
    console.log('baseB | ' + baseB);
    console.log('baseC | ' + baseC);
}
```

Потом пытаюсь выполнить требуемое:

```
function doSomething() {
    if (baseA !="") {
        console.log('true ' + baseA);
    }
    else {console.log('false')}
}

doSomething();
```

Лезу в `Options.html`, задаю параметры:

```
x = "aaa";
y = "bbb";
z = "ccc";
```

Лезу на страницу, где должен отработать контент скрипт и получаю в консоли вот такой результат:

```
false
baseA | aaa
baseB | bbb
baseC | ccc
```

То есть, функция `doSomething()` срабатывает раньше.
Вызывать `doSomething()` через `setTimeout` неинтересно, поскольку контент скрипт выполняется после загрузки документа, а сколько она займет времени, неизвестно.
Я так понимаю, это все из-за того, что `doSomething()` и `chrome.storage.sync.get` выполняются асинхронно. А что делать, чтобы гарантированно получить значения параметров до того, как мне они потребуются?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет способа работать с chrome.storage синхронно.
Однако вы можете подписаться на событие изменения storage: [chrome.storage.onChanges](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage#event-onChanged).

И еще: убедитесь что вы используете `chrome.storage.sync` верно, назначением которого является перенос настроек расширения между компьютерами пользователя (через сервера Google).

В случае, если вам требуется хранить настройки расширения локально: лучше воспользоваться `chrome.storage.local`, который, к тому же, работает немного быстрее.

Стоит заметить, что документация Chrome API говорит о том, что, если в браузере не включена синхронизация, sync работает так же - как local:

> When Chrome is offline, Chrome stores the data locally. The next time
>   the browser is online, Chrome syncs the data. Even if a user disables
>   syncing, storage.sync will still work. In this case, it will behave
>   identically to storage.local.